# Checkmark for switching Apple-ID password on icloud.com

Tags: icloud, security, apple-id, password

I have a little question which hopefully some of you can answer me.

You can switch your Apple-ID password in different ways. One for example is on the device settings itself or via webbrowser on any PC.

Now there is one little thing I have seen and now I am wondering if there is any difference and maybe some of you can tell me. When you log into icloud.com and then go from there to change your apple-id password, you have this checkmark at the bottom on the window where you enter your new password. It sais "Sign out of devices and websites using my Apple-ID". You see an random example picture from the internet here.

[image: Here you can see the checkmark]

Now I am wondering, does it matter if I change the password on my iPhone where I cant check this additional thing or is this done anyways. I just want to make sure that when I change the password it does sign out everywhere (Websites and devices and whatever else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are changing your password because you believe your password was stolen and someone has signed into your account, then that checkbox forces them to be signed out and enter your new password to re-gain access.

If you are changing your password because you want to improve your security, that checkbox is unnecessary. Your new password is required to add any future devices, so unless you believe someone has already signed in it serves no purpose.

Comment: Sounds right... So if i just switch it in the iphone security check for example I dont log out anyone is at least a reentering of the new passord necessary on other devices?

Comment: Changing a password does not log out other devices unless you check the box shown on the website. If you're on the phone, you can also look at the device list and remove any you don't recognize.